# change input data on rails model and save as another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

On a Rails model I have two fields :title and :text_id; text_id is a standardized format of Title i.e title = "Some Movie", text_id = "some-movie". In the model I have the following code:

```
before_save :get_link
def get_link
  self.text_id = 
end
```

What should self.text_id be equal to, to enable the formatting of title?

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
self.text_id = self.title.downcase.gsub(" ","-")
```